# What is "U" means in "gender" value?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I found "Gender" value in page_fans_gender_age (/insights/page_fans_gender_age/lifetime) state as M, F and U. What is U stand for?

This is could be undefined or Unknown. Just looked on registration page there has only Male and Female and it is mandatory field. If this for unknown, how FB define this?

Comment: It might be mandatory now, but it wasn't necessarily when the very first Facebook user signed up.  Unknown is my guess.

Answer (score 2):

it is "costum" .

*In an overdue move, Facebook has changed its options so that users can customize their gender beyond the two m/f boxes*, and added a costum gender.

I took my answer from this [link](http://www.goodasyou.org/good_as_you/2014/02/mf-___-facebook-allows-users-to-customize-gender.html)